# Laravel - How can I new instance and use in any Controller method

Tags: php, laravel

Hi   I want to know how to new global object for any method in controller

I found problem when I create non-static method in other class
and when to use them, I need to new instance in any method.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use DB;
    use App\Article; 
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Custom_Class\Schedule;   


    class ArticleController extends Controller
    {

   // $schedule_obj = new Schedule();  //Try this outside method but not work
        public function index()
        {

           $schedule_obj = new Schedule();
           $schedule_obj->sayHi();


        }
        public function someAction()
        {
            $schedule_obj = new Schedule();  //I do not want to new instance again.
             $schedule_obj->sayHi();
        }
```

Comment: Do it in constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate a new `Schedule` instance in your *constructor* and assign it to a *private* class-wide variable. Then you can access your single `Schedule` instance in every method.

**Example**

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /** @var Schedule Instance of the Schedule class. */
    private $schedule;

    /**
     * ArticlesController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->schedule = new Schedule();
    }

    /**
     * Does the #index() method thing.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->schedule->sayHi();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a controller you can user `__construct` method, but if you want to have it in application scope you can use Laravel `singleton` pattern